# Alpha - Image Texture problem

Tags: transparency

[image]
Hello, I am designing low quality alpha hair for a character I created, and when I use image texture on the meshes I made in blender, I encounter such an image. The texture does not appear as it should. Transparent and small details are completely erased. It looks noisy. What is the reason of this?

When I look at the same process in the 3D part of Photoshop, the result looks perfect. I want my texture to look like it does in photoshop.

How can I solve this problem?

The first two images are from blender. The last one is from Photoshop :

Comment: Maybe check the Image Texture settings, like choose Closest instead of Linear? Or pack your images and share your file so that we can check?

Comment: there is a lot of information missing. You seem to use Cycles as preview engine. How does it look like in EEVEE? Does the result change whenn you increase the samples setting of Cycles?

Comment: Be aware there is a separate samples setting for preview render. Have you tried an actual render? What does it look like?

Comment: It looks like you have a separate plane on top of the head, and therefore some rays are going through the transparency, some don't, but if you get just one sample per pixel, you will get a dithering, where a pixel has either hair color or body color, with probability based on alpha. You need at least two samples per pixel for SOME pixels to be an average: but with 2 samples you only support 50% alpha, when one sample hits the body, and the other hits the hair, and due to randomness involved you are not guaranteed the 50% alpha won't get two samples hitting hair or 2 samples hitting the body…

Comment: if you share your file: [How to upload a blend file on BSE - good practices and advice](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3050/60486) we might suggest how to do it better, that is, calculate the color once, on a single object, requiring just one sample per pixel (at least for this effect, other things like lightning, reflections, soft silhouette etc. require more samples still)

Comment: Guys, really thank you for your answers! I'm new to this so I couldn't understand a lot of what you said... Hahah sorry! I think I need to start all over again with a good tutorial.

Is there a nice and simple tutorial you can recommend for what I want to do, which I think can be called Alpha Hair design? What I find on YouTube is a bit challenging for me...

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do. However, I think the program used in this video is not Blender. It looks like 3ds max. The texture he added to the meshes looks very clear. Link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_kR4sXeOLKw&t=159s

Comment: Please share your file so that we can check it, make sure that you've packed your image (File > External Data > Pack Resources)